# Identify the exact time/date that someone has looked at your profile

Tags: api, rest, linkedin-api

Is it possible to identify the exact time/date that someone has looked at your profile on LinkedIn? At present you get a notification saying 'XYZ looked at your profile', and this seems to be within the last 24hrs, but is it possible to say exactly when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the LinkedIn support and they said that currently it's not possible.